# ldapsearch filter string letter , capital letter, '.' ,'-','_' and '@'

Tags: ldap

I'm doing a ldapsearch. I want all of my uid who have letter, capital letter, number, '.', '_', and '@' . I start with this code but I don't find the  filter

```
ldapsearch -x -D "cn=Directory Manager" -w secretsia -h 127.0.0.1 -p 389 -LLL -b "dc=sia" "uid=*.*_**-*\@*
```

Answer (score 1):

The uid attribute is not generally a case sensitive string, which means 'Bob', 'BOB', and 'bob' will all find the same accounts. Additionally, while LDAP filters can perform substring searches, full regular expression syntax cannot be used in the ldapsearch filter.

I'd write some code that uses LDAP, search for uid=*, retrieve the uid value, and then apply the appropriate logic to identify UIDs you want. Alternately, you can use ldapsearch to dump all of the uids and write some code (or just use grep) to isolate lines that match your requirements.